# How can I subscribe to a Team Calendar comprised of multiple Calendars?

Tags: outlook, confluence

Using Confluence version 4.1.9.  The situation is that we have each individual employee with a Team Calendar in order to enter public events (vacation, jury duty, etc.)  Further, each 'team' has created a wiki page that contains a calendar that shows all of the team member's calendars, thusly

[image: Team Calendar]

We would now like to be able to sync that meta-calendar back to Microsoft Outlook, hopefully without having to force each Outlook user to manually add the entire set of calendars in the meta-calendar.

How can I set it up so that Microsoft Outlook users can subscribe to Confluence calendars of this sort?

Comment: Have you checked this page: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/TEAMCAL/Subscribe+to+Team+Calendars+from+Microsoft+Outlook ? If your "combined" calendar is also a Team Calendar, then to my understanding the link I provided should solve your issue.

Comment: @MaksimLuzik I've been through that page.  The difficulty I have with it is that these "macro calendars" or "combined calendars" seem to lack the '...' button that is described, and don't have any (apparent) way to actually "subscribe" to them.